# Where can I discover what policies can be set via PolicyKit?

Tags: documentation, policykit

PolicyKit can be used to implement a variety of rules, including:

- controlling shutdown/restart rights
- disabling/enabling hibernation
- controlling network configuration rights

and so on.

I'd like to know where, if anywhere, such configurable actions are documented, in a human-readable manner. In case this is too broad, where can I find information about policies that are supported by software installed as part of `ubuntu-desktop`? Preferably online and well-formatted, if not, at least not XML.

I know that `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` contains XML files describing most, if not all, supported actions, but XML is not very human-readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a central online repository providing documentation of all possible Polkit actions.

But you can display a human-readable listing of all installed actions with `pkaction --verbose` (See this [pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8513557/) for my own system - running 14.04/unity).

Example with just `com.canonical.indicator.sound.AccountsService.ModifyOwnUser`:

```
com.canonical.indicator.sound.AccountsService.ModifyOwnUser:
  description:       Set properties of own user
  message:           Authentication is required to set one's own indicator sound properties.
  vendor:            
  vendor_url:        
  icon:              
  implicit any:      yes
  implicit inactive: yes
  implicit active:   yes
```

Most of the actions policy files in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` are installed by packages which are (direct or not) dependencies of `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: A central repository is not necessary, I would be happy with each provider's individual websites. For example, Googling `com.canonical.indicator.sound.AccountsService` or `org.freedesktop.login1` or `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings` don't really show any pages which document them (worse, some are source files on Github). Thanks for `pkaction`, though.